# Java Eclipse Swing: Error al compilar un metodo ya funcional

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse

Eclipse no me permite ejecutar mi aplicacion ya que me lanza lo siguiente:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Conexion.LlenadoCombo(Conexion.java:177)

```
public void LlenadoCombo(JComboBox CBEntradas){
    rs=Consulta("select * from informativo");
    try{
        while(rs.next()){
            CBEntradas.addItem(rs.getString("idInformativo")+": "+rs.getString("asunto"));
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

El error es marcado en la linea 4 `while(rs.next()){`

Es un método de llenado de items `String` a un `JComboBox` desde una base de datos SQL Server, no he tenido ningun error en la conexión y tengo una conexión de manera local por lo que descarto un error de ese origen. **Anteriormente ya había compilado**, el error me surgió tras agregar una línea de código en otro evento del la clase principal. Sin embargo dicha línea de código no utiliza ninguna de las variables de este método ni modifica algún atributo importante de la clase principal.

¿Alguna solución o es acaso un bug de Eclipse?

Comment: Eso no es un error de compilación... Y cualquier `NullPointerException` acaba siendo "lo que hay a la izquierda de un punto es `null`"; en este caso el `rs`.

Comment: El código compila y funciona según lo esperado. Tu problema es que el método `Consulta` no está devolviendo un `ResultSet`. Provee el código de este método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es a través del joptionpane o te detiene la app? Pregunto porque si sabes eso podes saber donde esta el error, si se crashea sabes que esta aca:
rs=Consulta("select * from informativo");

rs que es?

Te recomiendo hacer testing unitario con JUnit para ahorrarte este tipo de problemas, saludos!

Comment: Disculpa logre solucionar esto, recuerdo que el error lo encontre en la base de datos misma el codigo como tal estaba bien, rs era un tipo de dato ResultSet y el metodo Colsulta(String) tenia un SQLException para ver si ocurria error dentro de. Igual gracias por la respuesta